# ActiveRecord, excluding a record !=?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following, which gives me a list of comments:

```
@comments = record.commentable.comments
```

record in this case is a comment captured by an observer. What I want to do is get a list of comments excluding the recent comment, which in this case is record.

I tried the following but it errors with

> "ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):"

```
@comments = record.commentable.comments.where(:id != record.id)
```

Suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@comments = record.commentable.comments.where('id <> ?' , record.id)
```

More info here:

- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3